# How to merge pushed two commits?

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

I committed and pushed some files via `git commit .` followed by `git push`.

Then, I found that there were some mistakes in the files. I fixed ti. Then, I recommitted and re-pushed. So, I now see two separate commits in `git log`, which is ugly.

Can I merge these two pushed commits into one?

Comment: In the future, consider using `git commit --amend`, which amends the previous commit. Then push with `git push --force` which will overwrite the previous commit. @AdamT's advice on shared repositories still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. If no one else has pulled from the remote you can:

```
git rebase -i
```

Followed by:

```
git push origin +master
```

Please keep in mind that it is not recommended to `rebase` shared repositores and that `+master` will ignore it being fast forward.